# Ruby on Rails where_values method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

In Ruby on Rails 4 there was `where_values` method:

```
User.with_all_credentials(creds).where_values
[
    [0] "lower(email) = 'test'"
]
```

In Ruby on Rails 5 when I try to do the same it returns me that this method not exists. How can I get the same result in Ruby on Rails 5?

Comment: Is [this](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/where_values_hash) what you're looking for ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I tried that but in my example It returns empty hash.

Comment: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/c414fc6

Comment: I think that where_values was never public api, only where_values_hash was and is. The implementation of where_values_hash however changed: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fa779b380e61381a393afbc7bbc0a9ce07e0ce74/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L588 - not sure though why in your case where_values_hash is empty.

Comment: there is no clear boundary between public and supposedly private methods (which are actually public) in Active Record. Its completely confusing.

Comment: @apneadiving the boundary is the documentation: if it's `:nodoc:` then it's internal. It'd be nice if Ruby had a firmer way of enforcing that rule, but unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: @matthewd yeah, I regret they dont make methods private, would be no brainer :)

Comment: @apneadiving and what, make every second line in rails/rails use `.send(:foo)`? :/  What we really need is something like https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12962

Comment: @matthewd I am not sure we understood each other. What I mean is: if rails core team considers a method is private, then make it private. If you hack around using send, you'll know for sure you are doing it at your own risk. Keeping it public let all doors open.

Comment: @apneadiving Rails itself still needs to be able to call the method. If you have an idea of how to improve it, though, please do open a PR.

Comment: @matthewd public/private methods is part of any well structured app and doesnt prevent it from working. I made the remark once on rails and the answer was so brutal I dont intend to contribute

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it might be easily seen in the Rails code, it’s now [`where_clause`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-1-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb#L64).

(Because `where` lives now in [`CLAUSE_METHODS`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-1-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L10).)

Comment: [Ref from rails 4](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L7) to show the change

Answer (score 0):

i think this may help out:-
The replacement is either to use where_values_hash method or to introspect where_clause
https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/where_values_hash