# NoMethodError - undefined method `where_values' | Upgraded from rails 4.2 to 5.0.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, where-clause

I have recently upgraded my rails app from 4.2.8 to 5.0.1 with ruby 2.4.5
Facing this error

> NoMethodError - undefined method `where_values' for

Query:

> PlacementActivityStep.where(query_values_hash[:query_string], query_values_hash[:values])
> .**where_values**.select{|x| x.present?}

How do I achieve the same query in rails 5.0.1 using where_clause as where_values has been removed from the new rails version??
Reference: [Ruby on Rails where_values method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52052828/ruby-on-rails-where-values-method)

Comment: Is there anything unclear with the answer to the other question you linked to?

Comment: PlacementActivityStep.where(query_values_hash[:query_string], query_values_hash[:values]) .where_clause.select{|x| x.present?} gives NoMethodError - private method `select' called for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::WhereClause:0x000055f5501f8f10>. What to do now?

Comment: Does where_values_hash do the trick?

Comment: No. where_values_hash returns hash while where_values returns <Arel::Nodes::Equality: and where_clause returns <ActiveRecord::Relation::WhereClause:0x0000563d4ac68710 @predicates=[#<Arel::Nodes::Equality:0x0000563d4ac68b48 @left=#<struct Arel::Attributes::Attribute relation=#<Arel::Table:0x0000563d492ec160 @name="placement_activity_steps", @columns=nil ...

Answer (score 0):

Following is tested in `Rails 5.2.2`
First, `where_values` was not intended for public use, see https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12962
And to get the same behavior you must do some hacks.

I don't know what you will use the generated arel code for, I prefer to make the condition directly with arel if it's a complicated condition. And you will lose some automatic type detection.

Consider this (bad example but only to show the difference):

```
# model Foo have column 'bar' that is sql type string
Foo.where('bar = :one OR bar = :two', one: 55, two: nil ).to_sql
=> "SELECT `foos`.* FROM `foos` WHERE (firstname = 55 OR firstname = NULL)"
# bad, the last should be "firstname IS NULL"

# use Rails "magic"
Foo.where(bar: [ 55, nil ]).to_sql
=> "SELECT `foos`.* FROM `foos` WHERE (`foos`.`firstname` = '55' OR `foos`.`firstname` IS NULL)"
# "`firstname` IS NULL" as it should be (and '55' is a string)

# if it is the arel you want, you can use it directly
fo_a = Foo.arel_table
fo_a[:bar].eq_any([ 55, nil ]).to_sql
=> "(`foos`.`firstname` = '55' OR `foos`.`firstname` IS NULL)"

# that is the same as if you where using this in Rails 4:
Foo.where(bar: [ 55, nil ]).where_values.first.to_sql

# even if you use a hackish way you will not get the same result
Foo.where(bar: [ 55, nil ]).where_clause.send(:predicates).first.to_sql
=> "(`foos`.`firstname` = ? OR `foos`.`firstname` IS NULL)"
# '55' is gone (it's a "bind value")
```